# OpenGL Texture 2D arrays and mipmapping

Tags: opengl

I am trying to understand how to mipmap [texture arrays](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt) .From what I understand,texture array is 3 dimensional structure where each texture 2D has a depth param in glTexStorage3D which sets a given texture to some position in the array.But how do I specify number of mipmaps per texture?Can I specify different number of mipmaps per texture?

Is this the right way to do it?

```
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,10,GL_RGBA8,width,height,numTextures);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
for(int i =0 ; i <numTextures;++i){

    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,/*What goes here???*/, 0, 0, 0, width, height, /*What goes here?*/, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

 }

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
```

I don't know what to pass into second and 8 parameters of glTexSubImage3D. Should the second param be a number of mipmaps and the 8th - depth of the current texture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second param is the mipmap level of the texture you want to load. In your case, since you want to rely on GL to generate the mipmaps, it's 0.

The eighth parameter is the depth. In the case of arrays, that means the number of layers you're passing. For you, it's 1, since you're passing a single layer per iteration of the loop.

The 5th parameter, however, is the offset in depth of where you want to store the data you're passing in. In your case, it's the layer you're loading `i`.

Comment: see also the example at [www.opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture)

Comment: @BDL: yeah, I toyed with the idea to link to it, but it's not actually showing loading textures separately (which was a bit of a surprise to me, as you'd think it's the most natural way to do it)

Comment: @BDL that's the whole point,that example fails short to explain how to use the array texture.